# Showing path of current HTML-element in Netbeans?

Tags: php, html, netbeans

like in the screenshot from Adobe Dreamweaver below, I would like to show the path / the parents of the currently selected HTML-element in the windows's footer of Netbeans (for HTML- and PHP-documents including HTML). I think I've already seen it displayed once, so the feature should exist in Netbeans, but I don't know how to switch it on again?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please check (I don't have Netbeans installed so I can't test it): The feature you're looking for is probably called [***Breadcrumbs***](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB73#Breadcrumbs) According to the HTML5 integration, it's available for HTML, too: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HTML5 (If I'm not mistaken it) - https://netbeans.org/features/html5/

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution: in Netbeans, click on "Show Breadcrumbs" in the "View menu"